# Sort the products based on the frequency of changes in customer demand

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by, accumulate

Imagine following dataframe is given.

```
import pandas as pd 
products = ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Eggplant', 'Eggplant']
customer_demand_date = ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-07', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-07', '2023-01-14']
col_02_2023 = [0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 10]
col_03_2023 = [20, 30, 10, 0, 10, 0]
col_04_2023 = [10, 40, 50, 30, 40, 10]
col_05_2023 = [40, 40, 60, 50, 60, 20]

data = {'Products': products,
        'customer_demand_date': customer_demand_date,
        '02_2023': col_02_2023,
        '03_2023': col_03_2023,
        '04_2023': col_04_2023,
        '05_2023': col_05_2023}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df) 

Products customer_demand_date  02_2023  03_2023  04_2023  05_2023
0    Apple           2023-01-01        0       20       10       40
1    Apple           2023-01-07       20       30       40       40
2   Carrot           2023-01-01        0       10       50       60
3      Egg           2023-01-01        0        0       30       50
4      Egg           2023-01-07        0       10       40       60
5      Egg           2023-01-14        0        0       10       20
```

I have columns products, custome_demand_date (every week there is new customer demand for products per upcoming months) and months with quantity demand.
How can I determine which product has experienced the most frequent changes in customer demand over the months, and sort the products in descending order of frequency of change?
I have tried to group by product, accumulate the demand quantity but none of them can analyze the data both horizontally (per customer demand date) and vertically (per months).
Desired output:

```
Sorted products      Ranking(or %, or count of changes) 
Egg                  1 (or 70% or 13)   
Apple                2 (or 52% or 8)
Carrot               3 (22% or 3)
```

Either ranking or % of change frequency or count of changes.

- Note: percentages in desired output are random numbers

I'd really appreciate if you have any clever approach to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of "the most frequent changes in customer demand"?

Comment: So for ex: first week of Jan customer demanded 0 eggs for Feb, 0 for March, 30 for Apr, 50 for May. and the second week, customer changed his mind. now he wants 10 eggs for Feb, 40 for Apr and so on. 3rd week again there is some changes in demand quantity. I want to calculate which product has experienced most change, every time my dataset becomes bigger and bigger because there is new week and new demand. so every week there should be new product sorting whith descending order of frequency of change. I hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: Thats why I said analysis should be both horizontally and vertically. Because new customer demand is new row. And to track the changes I have to analyze how quantity changes from month to month also from old demand to new demand

Comment: @Sacha, what kind of output do you expect ? Can you add it to your question ?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have added desired output to the question. Basically it can be ranking or count of changes. Anything that can help to sort products

Comment: What is the meaning of `customer_demand_date` and the month columns (e.g., is the customer pre-ordering on that date for future months, or is it the first time of contact, etc.)? Also, please add an example calculation for the count of changes to your question (because I come up with different results, e.g., why is the count of changes for Apple not 5?).

Comment: yes, customer preordering for future months. You have calculated 5 because you've analyzed only parallelly(horizontally) (from month to month) but I also added changes from demand to demand(changes from 1st week to 2nd) (from 0 to 20, from 20 to 30 and from 10 to 40)

Comment: Your "frequent changes" measure appears to be a Cost Function. That is, a customer who keeps waffling has higher cost than rock solid customers -- his uncertainty impacts your supply chain planning. Put a dollar figure on it. Imagine his initial April order was 70 eggs, then he revised it to 20, so you're stuck with 50 perishable eggs and their costs. Or here's another common approach: define an error measure, such as [RMSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation), and rank on that. So tell us, please, what's your cost function?

Comment: @J_H I liked your explanation :) I dont have any cost function. Im new in this topic but you mention exactly the same problem that I have in real data. Thats why I want to find out which of the products causes more fluctuation. And then as a next step I will zoom in to that product and analyze its supply

Comment: somehow your "printed" df does not fit your defined df in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to define a function that counts horizontal and vertical changes which you can apply to each group individually.

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

def change_freq(x, months):
    # count horizontal changes
    chngs_horizontal = x[months].diff(axis=1).fillna(0).astype(bool).sum().sum()
    # count vertical changes
    chngs_vertical = x[months].diff(axis=0).fillna(0).astype(bool).sum().sum()
    return chngs_horizontal+chngs_vertical

# sample data
data = StringIO("""
Products,customer_demand_date,02_2023,03_2023,04_2023,05_2023
Apple,2023-01-01,0,20,10,40
Apple,2023-01-07,20,30,40,40
Carrot,2023-01-01,0,10,50,60
Egg,2023-01-01,0,0,30,50
Egg,2023-01-07,0,10,40,60
Egg,2023-01-14,0,0,10,20
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",")

# count horizontal and vertical changes by product
result = df.groupby('Products').apply(change_freq, ['02_2023','03_2023','04_2023','05_2023'])
result = result.sort_values(ascending=False).to_frame('count_changes')
result['rank'] = result['count_changes'].rank(ascending=False)
```

This returns

```
          count_changes  rank
Products
Egg                  13   1.0
Apple                 8   2.0
Carrot                3   3.0
```

Comment: Thanks, very clear approach.

Answer (score 1):

to find the variance in y direction a `groupby("Products")` with an lambda function can be used:

```
var_y=(df.loc[:,~df.columns.isin(['customer_demand_date','HEHE'])].groupby("Products").agg(lambda x: x.pct_change().fillna(0).astype(bool).sum())).reset_index(level=0)
```

to find the variance in x direction pct_change interpreted as True or False can be used using astype(bool):

```
var_x=pd.concat([df[["Products"]], df.iloc[:,2:].pct_change(axis='columns').replace(np.inf, 1).fillna(0).astype(bool).sum(axis=1).rename('sum_x')], axis=1)
```

adding / grouping both together would finally look like this:

```
   Products  sum_x  sum_y  sum_xy
0     Apple      5      3       8
1    Carrot      3      0       3
2  Eggplant      7      6      13
```

below the complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
products = ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Eggplant', 'Eggplant', 'Eggplant']
customer_demand_date = ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-07', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-07','2023-01-14']
col_02_2023 = [0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0]
col_03_2023 = [20, 30, 10, 0, 10, 0]
col_04_2023 = [10, 40, 50, 30, 40, 10]
col_05_2023 = [40, 40, 60, 50, 60, 20]

data = {'Products': products,
        'customer_demand_date': customer_demand_date,
        '02_2023': col_02_2023,
        '03_2023': col_03_2023,
        '04_2023': col_04_2023,
        '05_2023': col_05_2023}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
var_y=(df.loc[:,~df.columns.isin(['customer_demand_date','HEHE'])].groupby("Products").agg(lambda x: x.pct_change().fillna(0).astype(bool).sum())).reset_index(level=0)
var_y["sum_y"]=var_y.iloc[:,1:].sum(axis="columns")
var_x=pd.concat([df[["Products"]], df.iloc[:,2:].pct_change(axis='columns').replace(np.inf, 1).fillna(0).astype(bool).sum(axis=1).rename('sum_x')], axis=1)
var_x_sum=var_x.groupby("Products", as_index=False).agg(sum_x=('sum_x','sum'))
var_total=pd.concat([var_x_sum,var_y["sum_y"]],axis=1)
var_total["sum_xy"]=var_total.iloc[:,1:].sum(axis="columns")
print(var_total)
```